# Jmeter- Throughput increases after ehcache clear

Tags: performance, jmeter, ehcache

While executing Jmeter test on staging environment, we ran `ehcache clear` command, which removed all site cache. Since the `ehcache` got cleared, we were expecting that the performance and throughput would go down for some time. Instead, the number of transactions per second (throughput) increased drastically.

What can be the explanation for this?

Comment: We are still investigating this problem. We do have the response code assertion set.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug/wrong implementation of `ehcache`, you can check a detailed how [ehcache dissected](https://twasink.net/2005/10/20/ehcache-dissected/):

> ...database connections were kept open. Which meant that the database
> started to slow down. This meant that other activity started to take
> longer as well...

and in summary:

> for a non-distributed cache, it performs well enough as long as you
> configure it okay.

Also check [guidelines](https://www.wix.engineering/single-post/scaling-to-100m-to-cache-or-not-to-cache) which will conclude in an interesting way:

> we learned that we do not need a cache. In fact, in most cases where
> people introduce a cache it is not really needed. ...
> Our guidelines for using a cache are as follows:
>
> 1. You do not need a cache.
> 2. Really, you don’t.
> 3. If you still have a performance issue, can you
>    solve it at the source? What is slow? Why is it slow? Can you
>    architect it differently to not be slow? Can you prepare data to be
>    read-optimized?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not due to a slow EhCache configuration, I suppose explanation could be that :

- You don't have response assertion in your test plan so just base it on Response Code which might be 200 while response page was not the one you requested
- The page served after the clear, are maybe lighter (error pages ? default pages) and do not require as

See:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/best-practice-using-jmeter-assertions/